# Edit array in a mysql row via PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Ok, I making a website and there are "teams", the host of this team can add or remove users from the team.

Each team is a row in my SQL table, and I would like to store an array whit each member of the team in this row. When the host add or remove a member I want to take this array from the database edit it and put it back to the database.

Im using PDO.

```
$member_array = $bdd->query("SELECT members_array FROM teams WHERE ID = 1 ");
$member_array = $member_array->fetch();
```

> Then I modify $member_array (here is where I need help)

```
$insert_new_array = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO squads($member_array) VALUES(:$member_array)');
$insert_new_array -> execute(array( [...] ));
```

Is this the right way to do what I want?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use JSON. But you better do not store arrays in one cell and learn about relations.

Comment: It really is a bad design to store an array in a single column. You may want to rethink your design.

Comment: Like others commented before me - you don't edit textual columns that contain serialized data, you add, delete or update rows. That's why **relational** databases are powerful - they establish **relations** between tables. A table is data structure. A powerful one. Don't use it as a text file. Do what Paul an Jay suggested.